# Converse of casorati weierstrass theorem proof check

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I'd like to prove the converse of Casorati-Weierstrass theorem, i.e: if $f$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb{C}\setminus \{w\}$ and for all open set $V$ containing $w$ we have $f(V\setminus \{w\})$ is dense in $\Bbb{C}$, then $w$ is an essential singularity of $f$.

Here is my solution:

As $f(V\setminus \{w\})$ is dense in $\Bbb{C}$, for all $\epsilon>0, x \in \Bbb{C}$ we have $B(x,\epsilon)\cap f(V\setminus \{w\})\neq \emptyset$. Thus for all $z\in V\setminus \{w\}) $we have $|f(z)-x|\le \epsilon \iff |f(z)|\le \epsilon+|x| \iff |z-w|^N|f(z)|\le (\epsilon+|x|)|z-w|^N \ \forall N\ge 1$. And so $|z-w|^N |f(z)|\to 0$ as $z\to w \ \forall N\ge 1$ which shows that $w$ is an essential singularity of $f$. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you've essentially proved that $f$ has a removable singularity at $w$ which is not at all what you want to prove, and also is false.

Here is a correct proof: $f$ has an isolated singularity which can be a removable singularity, a pole or an essential singularity.
One can easily show that if $w$ is a pole for $f$, then $|f| \to \infty$ as $z \to w$, so the image of small enough neighborhoods cannot be dense because it only contains numbers large in module. If you have a removable singularity, then your function is bounded in any neighbourhood, so again, the image cannot be dense. The only remaining possibility is that your singularity is essential.